# Does Explain command in mysql misleads?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've a table `Employee`, and as of now it has 21 columns and 611,028 rows.

When I run following query,

```
select count(*) from employee where employee.joined_at > '2016-02-15';
```

> Output: 81632

When I run following `explain` query,

```
explain select count(*) from employee where employee.joined_at > '2016-02-15';
```

Output is as follows,

```
id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys   | key             | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | SIMPLE      | employee | range | index_joined_at | index_joined_at | 9       | null | 158216 | Using where
```

As you can see no. of rows scan is quite high when compare to actual `count`. How is it possible? Can I ever trust `explain` command to optimize my queries? If yes, then when?

I'm on mysql version `5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1`. I found similar article [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/10/13/when-explain-estimates-can-go-wrong/). But it didn't explained me the reason for this behavior. So, when can I trust `explain` command of mysql?

My table create command (I've renamed column names for security purpose)

```
CREATE TABLE `Employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column 2` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `column 3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `column 4` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `column 5` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `column 6` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `column 7` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `column 8` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `column 9` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `joined_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `column 12` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `column 13` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_no` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `column 15` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'Cold',
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column 18` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `column 19` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `column 20` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `column 21` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `index_joined_at` (`joined_at`),
  KEY `index_phone_no` (`phone_no`),
  KEY `index_status` (`status`),
  KEY `index_email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=627960 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: as per the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html): `rows` - **ESTIMATE** of rows to be examined.

Comment: InnoDB is really bad at guessing. The numbers can be off by a factor of 100.

Comment: @MarcB but why is the number almost double? :|

Comment: because it's a GUESS. it's like saying "There will be 100 people at this party, because I sent out 100 invitations". well, no, not everyone is going to accept or be available.